# Compare date from database with current date - Java

Tags: java, sql, date, variables, compare

I have a problem with types of date variables... I need to take date from database and compare it with current date... I think that I get date from database in right way, but I don't know how to take current date in same type of date variable to can compare it.. In my database format for saving data of date is "DATE" yyyy-mm-dd.

```
                Date now = new Date();  
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+textField_Username.getText()+"' AND password='"+textField_Password.getText().toString()+"'";
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if(rs.next()) {
                    Date expire = new Date(rs.getDate("account_expire").getTime());
                    if(expire.before(now)){
                        
                    }
                    dispose();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Sucessfully.");
                    Workshop window = new Workshop();
                    window.frmCfWorkshop.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username and password...");
                }
```

Comment: CAREFUL: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Do not ever inject user input straight into your SQL. Use PreparedStatements instead.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I know this is just a start of coding